# Communication between python applications

Tags: python, multithreading, server, client

I'm having trouble finding a good solution for a client server system where the clients make requests to the server and the server responds with the result. The server needs to be independent from the clients, i.e. if I create a new python application I want to easily be able to connect to the server and send requests. One possible solution I know of is using sockets, but that feels unnecessary complicated. I've tried looking into using Managers but I'm not sure if it's on the right track.

My goal is to have something working like this:

```
result = server.send("2+2") # result should now be 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [**`ZeroMQ`**](http://zeromq.org/bindings:python). It can be used point to point like a super powered socket and looks nice and clean in your code like your example. [**This** example](http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/client_server.html) shows how easy it can be.

Or you could do a simple `REST` interface using a light weight web service framework like [**`Bottle`**](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html) or [**`Flask`**](http://flask.pocoo.org/) on the server side. Those can run stand alone at first for ease of use and later put them behind a web server ([**`nginx`**](https://nginx.org/en/docs/) with [**`uwsgi`**](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for example) later for performance. On the client side talk to it with regular python [requests module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

Answer (score 0):

Once I played with these things (in Python) and here's an example (don't mind the code style, format, efficiency, as they are lame, lots of NO-NOs from programming's PoV, just look at it as it was a starting point):

> server.py:

```
import sys
import select
from SocketServer import TCPServer, StreamRequestHandler

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 12345

class DummyRequestHandler(StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        text = ""
        while 1:
            if select.select([self.rfile], [], [], 0.5)[0] == [self.rfile]:
                char = self.rfile.read(1)
                if char == ";":
                    break
                else:
                    text += char

        try:
            result = eval(text)
        except Exception as e:
            result = str(e)
        self.wfile.write(str(result) + ";")

print "Listening on %s:%d" % (HOST, PORT)
server = TCPServer((HOST, PORT), DummyRequestHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

> client.py:

```
import sys
import socket
import select

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 12345
EXIT_TEXT = "EXIT"

text = ""
while not text:
    text = raw_input("Enter text to send (%s to exit) :" % EXIT_TEXT)
    if text.upper() == EXIT_TEXT:
        print "Exiting"
        sys.exit(0)
if text[-1] != ";":
    text += ";"
s4 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s4.connect((HOST, PORT))
s4.send(text)
reply = ""
while 1:
    if select.select([s4], [], [], 0.5)[0] == [s4]:
        char = s4.recv(1)
        if char == ";":
            break
        else:
            reply += char
print "Server replied: %s\n" % reply
s4.close()
```

I've tested it using *Python2.7.10* on *Win*. It works with simple expressions.